# `CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE` on login with Python JIRA

Tags: python, windows, jira

**Test script:**

```py
from jira import JIRA

user_name = "my username"
password = "my password"
jira_conn = JIRA(server='http://my.server.com',
                basic_auth=(user_name, password))
```

---

**Error:**

```
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 403 url: http://my.server.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo
    text: CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE; login-url=http://my.server.com/login.jsp
    
    response headers = {'X-AREQUESTID': '1036x605910x1', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1;mode=block',
                        'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff',
                        'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
                        'Content-Security-Policy': "frame-ancestors 'self'",
                        'X-ASEN': 'SEN-2105411', 'Set-Cookie': 'JSESSIONID=3D489D7D7A533761610029A9FEBEDE83; Path=/; HttpOnly',
                        'X-Seraph-LoginReason': 'AUTHENTICATION_DENIED',
                        'WWW-Authenticate': 'OAuth realm="http%3A%2F2Fmy.server.com"',
                        'X-ASESSIONID': '161938n',
                        'X-Authentication-Denied-Reason': 'CAPTCHA_CHALLENGE; login-url=http://my.server.com/login.jsp',
                        'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=UTF-8',
                        'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Date': 'Mon, 29 Jun 2020 15:16:49 GMT'}
    response text =
```

1. The first time I got this error I went to a browser, logged off then in again and in addition to `user`+`password`, a *captcha* was asked.

   1.1. Login page asked for this *captcha* a few times (this is not necessarily surprising) and finally succeeded.
2. Now I can log in and out from my JIRA server as many times as I want and it works at first *in browser*.
3. No matter the conditions I try, this simple code is no longer able to log in (and it was working perfectly until a day before).

   1.1. I tried changing `basic_auth` to `auth`. No luck.

---

**Questions:**

- Shouldn't a browser succesful log in clear the *captcha* state?
- I tried to follow Atlassian [Cookie-based authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/cookie-based-authentication/):

```sh
curl -X POST http://my.server.com/jira/rest/auth/1/session -H jira/rest/auth/1/session -d '{ "username": "my username", "password": "my password" }'
```

but response is:

```html
<h1>Oops, you&#39;ve found a dead link.</h1>
```

How can I find the correct URL for `my.server.com`?

- Which additional info is relevant here.
- What else can I test?

---

**Environment**

- Python 3.8 and Python 2.7.
- Py-jira: jira>=2.0.0
- Client is Rwindows-10.
- JIRA server version:
  `Atlassian Jira Project Management Software (v8.3.1#803002-sha1:00bd3db)`

---

Thanks!

---

**EDIT***

I managed to make `curl` work simply like this:

```sh
curl -X POST 'http://my.server.com' --data '{ "username": "my user", "password": "my password" }'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my vim plugin [vira](https://github.com/n0v1c3/vira) we did find using the `basic_auth` as the quickest way along with adding in an extra `async_` option. However, I believe the issue will be that you need to verify your login through the browser or program.

In other words once you fail to login through the code you will need to confirm you are not just code **trying** to login, it is the same as if you failed to login through the browser enough times in a row.

We have this issue while developing as well and simply open the browser, login, enter the hard to read text and try again. Once your code is stable it is not an issue until the next issue.

Depending on the sever as well you may need the API token vs your Password. I have another example of that on my README for Atlassian cloud projects.

```
     # verify: will set ssl verification requirements (should be True by default)
           
        if 'https://' not in server.lower():
            server = 'https://' + server
        try:
            self.jira = JIRA(
                    options={
                        'server': server,
                        'verify': cert_verify,
                    },
                    basic_auth=(username, password),
                    timeout=2,
                    async_=True,
                    max_retries=2)
        except JIRAError as e:
            if 'CAPTCHA' in str(e):
                print(e)
```

`JIRAError` is quite useful for catching/printing the error in details.

`if 'CAPTCHA' in str(e):` catch CAPTCHA